# How to install Google API PHP Client with Composer? (to use with php-gds lib and Google App Engine)

Tags: google-app-engine, composer-php, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to install the Google API PHP Client using Composer https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client#composer
I've never used Composer before, but I've downloaded and installed it (on Win 7).

I wasn't sure what to do next or what to put where, if anything.
Without downloading the Google API Client, I just went into my PHP project's folder on the command line and entered:

```
composer require google/apiclient:^2.0.0@RC
```

which did some stuff and then threw back:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package google/apiclient could not be found in any version,
there may be a typo in the package name.
```

I also tried manually downloading the API Client package (latest 2.0RC6 release), unpacking it into my PHP project dir, CD into that and doing the same composer command again. Got same error.

I'm building a PHP project on Google App Engine using the excellent [PHP-GDS](https://github.com/tomwalder/php-gds) library to access Cloud Datastore and need the API Client to use the Gateway JSON API interface working (so I can try projection queries). Without that I'm getting the error `Fatal error: Class 'Google_Client' not found in GDS\Gateway\GoogleAPIClient.php on line 87`

I haven't used Composer to install php-gds. My understanding is that Composer will only bring the needed .php files from a lib into my project so unneeded ones are not uploaded to App Engine or included at run-time?

Anyway, any help much appreciated! (especially explicit steps of what to do!)

Many thanks.

Comment: Hi Alex. Currently the 2.0 RC branch is only supported by a dev branch of PHP-GDS. however. 1.1.6 is supported by the main release branch.

Comment: Thanks Tom. Is that the reason for the errors I was seeing do you think, or what steps do I need to take to get the Google API Client installed (which I assume needs Composer)? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Simply install with

```
composer require google/apiclient
```

Google is terrible at updating their docs.

Comment: Would you mind telling me and everyone else where exactly I should type that piece of code???????????

Comment: @ekashking composer is a command-line tool that allows you to install PHP packages so you would type that on the command line.

Comment: I found that I was getting errors saying oauth2 was not found.  I tried everything to fix and when trying to install this using composer require google/auth got a message saying it couldnt include its self in the composer.json file so I deleted composer.json, added the google/auth as the first package then added compser require google/apiclient afterwards and this worked without errors.  It seems it matters which order you add packages when using composer.  FYI his was using PHP 8.2.3 and IIS10 on a Windows 10 VM